# Stratified sampling in R with unequal weights and replacement

Tags: r, sampling

I have a large data set with a field containing a combined FIPS code and zip code, and another data set with population weighted centroids for block groups combined with some zip code data. I want to stratify my data by "FIPS code" and then assign each row a set of coordinates for a block group centroid, where the centroid's probability of being selected is proportional to its population.

I was originally using a sample of the data (1000 rows) and the strata function from the sampling package, which worked fine. Now that I want to do this for every row in the data set, however, I'm getting this error:

```
Error in strata(popCenters2, stratanames = "FIPS", method = "systematic",  : 
 not enough obervations in the stratum 1
```

I suspect that this is because strata does not use replacement and my data set is much larger than the centroid data set.

This is the code I used with the strata function applied to my sample:

```
## Combined fields to match format of other data
popCenters2 <- within(popCenters2, 
                 FIPS <- paste(stateFIPS, 
                               countyFIPS, 
                               zipcode, 
                               sep = ""))

sample %>% group_by(FIPS) %>% count() -> sampleCounts

popCenters2[order(popCenters2$FIPS), ] -> popCenters2
sampleCounts[order(sampleCounts$FIPS), ] -> sampleCounts

st = strata(popCenters2, stratanames = "FIPS", method = "systematic", size = 
sampleCounts$n, pik = popCenters2$contribPop)
stTable = getdata(popCenters2, st)
```

My sample had 5 rows with the "FIPS" variable equal to 4200117325, this is the centroid data corresponding to that:

```
FIPS       tract  blkGroup latitude longitude   contribPop
4200117325 030200 1      +40.000254 -077.137559 452
4200117325 030200 2      +39.959070 -077.160354 324
4200117325 030400 1      +39.915855 -077.406954 194
4200117325 030400 2      +39.923503 -077.298505 131
4200117325 030400 3      +39.878509 -077.307547 173
4200117325 030400 4      +39.873705 -077.360488 176
4200117325 030400 5      +39.880362 -077.412175 108
4200117325 030500 1      +39.926149 -077.227283 630
4200117325 030500 2      +39.921269 -077.260640 459
```

My question is, how can I reproduce this sort of procedure if, for example, my actual data set has 20 rows corresponding to 4200117325? I've read through the documentation for the strata function and a few others (Strata from DescTools, the survey package) but have been unable to find anything that allows replacement.